# Acro and package option short-format: “Missing control sequence inserted”

Tags: acro

This example fails to compile with `Missing control sequence inserted`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[short-format={\scshape}]{acro}
%\acsetup{short-format={\scshape}}
\DeclareAcronym{acc}{short=a, long=A}
\begin{document}  
\ac{acc}
\end{document}
```

Putting the package option inside of `\acsetup` instead solves the problem.

Is this a (known?) bug? Is it expected? (I don’t think I’ve seen anything about this in the manual, but I could have missed it, or perhaps my version of Acro (2.7) is outdated.)

Comment: package options are expanded when processed (for all packages), so yes it is expected that fragile commands breaks.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, that’s the answer I looked for. Perhaps this question should then be closed as a duplicate, or your comment become an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optional argument of `\usepackage` is less than ideal for key/value options. The problem in your case is that options when set through `\usepackage` *are expanded*. This is not only true for `acro` but for every package. This fact can always be (and often is) a problem when you put commands (like `\scshape`, …) there.

`acro` does allow settings options with `\usepackage` for no other reason than that people are used to set options there. You should simply use `\acsetup` – which was always the preferred and intended way to set `acro`'s options, anyway.

---

PS: Future versions of `acro` might not allow using “traditional” options any more.